# Unable to access button in different frame in a web page using vbscript in uft

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I am not able to access a button in a different frame. The part of HTML code for button is:

```
<input value=" New " class="btn" type="button" name="newAcctButton">
```

For the frame is:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" height="6500px" id="itarget" name="itarget" scrolling="auto" src="/servlet/servlet.Integration?lid=01NA0000000aPXG&amp;enc=UTF-8&amp;ic=1" title="Content" width="100%"></iframe>
```

I am trying that standard format `Browser(browsername).Page(pagename).Frame("name:=itarget").getElementByName("newAcctButton").Click`

I know this can be easily handled using Record and Playback functionality in QTP.

**Is it possible to switch to different frame (like we do in selenium webdriver) and access the web button?**

Comment: Please, instead of adding comments with more code, just edit your question and include these missing data.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `getElementByName` method in UFT unless you would like to use native object events.

It Should be like this.

```
Browser(browsername).Page(pagename).Frame("name:=itarget").WebButton("name:=newAcctButton").Click
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am aware of this WebButton functionality. However, i would like to understand, how we could use vbscript to switch to a different frame and access a button in it.

Comment: In the above VBS statement, you are accessing the frame first to get the button.  Browser(browsername).Page(pagename).Frame("name:=itarget") --> You are switching to frame.

Comment: @vins - Could you please tell me why you chose the name attribute instead of Id ?